# Pig - Order by - Different reducers?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm new to pig. I'm trying to do a merge join. To meet the following requirement:

> Data must be sorted on join keys in ascending (ASC) order on both
>   sides.

Sample File:

```
4, The Object of Beauty, 1991,2.8,6150 
1, The Nightmare Before Christmas, 1993,3.9,4568 
2, The Mummy, 1932,3.5,4388 
3, Orphans of the Storm, 1921,3.2,9062 
3, Orphans of the Storm, 1921,3.2,9062
4, The Object of Beauty, 1991,2.8,6150 
5, Night Tide, 1963,2.8,5126 
6, One Magic Christmas, 1985,3.8,5333 
7, Muriel's Wedding, 1994,3.5,6323 
8, Mother's Boys, 1994,3.4,5733 
9, Nosferatu: Original Version, 1929,3.5,5651 
10, Nick of Time, 1995,3.4,5333
```

I executed the following commands, inside PIG:

```
movies = LOAD 'Sample.csv' using PigStorage (',') as (id: int, name, year, rating, duration); 
movies_sorted movies = order by id ASC PARALLEL 3; 
movies_sorted store into 'output_movies';
```

When I execute:

> hadoop fs-cat ./output2/part-r-00000

I see that, there are records with equal keys in different partitions. For example, i have the record with id 3, in two different partitions. To my knowledge, records with the same key should always be in the same partition. F

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a few cases, including `ORDER BY` and skewed `JOIN`, Pig will break the map-reduce convention of sending all records for a given key to just one reducer. (Note that the notion of ordering is already outside the map-reduce paradigm.) You are still guaranteed, however, that if you traverse the output of the reducers in order (as indicated by the number in `part-r-NNNNN`), the records will be ordered as specified.

You can read more in [this thread](http://grokbase.com/t/pig/user/101j9e28xh/skewed-optimizations).

Comment: Thanks! You are right! Is there any command in pig that sends same keys to same reducers? If not, what can i use to meet this requirement, to execute a merge join. Do i need to create a IdentityMapper/Reducer. I will try Zebra, too.

Comment: A merge join is a map-only job, so you won't have reducers at all. There are tricks you can use to add a reduce phase that does enforce a one-reducer-per-key criterion, but I'm not even clear on why you need a merge join in the first place. If you're still interested, I'd recommend asking another question, taking into consideration the foregoing.

Comment: I know the merge-join is a map-only job, but to execute it, i need to meet the requirement: Data must be sorted on join keys in ascending (ASC) order on both sides. And i don't know how meet this requirement executing a map-reduce job.

Comment: Having all records for a key in a single input *file* is not a requirement for a merge join. The only requirement is that the data be sorted, and as long as the data is ordered using `ORDER BY`, the requirement will be satisfied.

Comment: Really, what i am trying to do is execute a map-side join from a map-reduce job, using CompositeInputFormat. To use CompositeInputFormat: "Each input dataset must be divided into the
same number of partitions, and it must be sorted by the same key (the join key) in each source.  All the records for a particular key must reside in the same partition and which is mandatory."

Comment: I think you should ask a new question about performing the join and put all details about your needs there. Why wouldn't you just use Pig's merge join? Are you using CompositeInputFormat with Pig? Why?

Comment: Because while I am performing the join, I'll be performing some aggregates calculations on the records. For example, how many times a record appeared within a date range. I will perform these calculations within the mapper function. (in-mapper combining design pattern) 

I'm using CompositeInputFormat off the pig, in a map-reduce job created by me. I was just using the PIG to meet the requiriment, having all records with the same key within the same partition.